# Including a directory as a search path during compilation with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to create an iOS project that includes C code that is shared across other platforms (Android). Some of the third party libraries I'm compiling rely on having certain directories included as search paths. However, no matter what I've tried, I've been unable to the CocoaPods `.podspec` file to include a given directory in the compilation search path. I'm using CocoaPods `1.8.4`.

Whilst this is a Flutter plugin, it's my understanding that this is an issue with CocoaPods/Xcode, since Flutter has merely set up the project files. However, it's worth noting that Flutter sets up an example workspace, which I do not want to modify. I want the Plugin itself to be modified to compile in the requisite code, not the example workspace/project. In other words, I want only the `ios/repro_cocoapods_issue.podspec` file to be modified.

In case it matters, I used the following Flutter command to create the project:

```
flutter create -t plugin -i objc -a java repro_cocoapods_issue
```

I have a full repro up on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kentcb/repro_cocoapods_issue). To reproduce, open the workspace at `example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode and try to build.

These are the things I've tried in the `ios/repro_cocoapods_issue.podspec` file:

- `s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.xcconfig = { 'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PROJECT_DIR}/external/"'}`
- `s.compiler_flags = '-Iexternal/'`
- `s.preserve_paths = 'external/**'`
- `s.preserve_paths = '${PROJECT_DIR}/external/**'`

In all cases, I get:

```
'external_dir.c' file not found
```

If I change the code to `#include ../external/external_dir.c` then it works, but this does not help with my actual use case.

> **How can I configure my podspec so that a specified directory is included in the search path during compilation?**

### Output of `pod env`

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.8.4
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
       Xcode : 11.1 (11A1027)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ d13a0869021d940f32f0543a03500755b39be998
```

#### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to put a local include directory into a podspec would you as it only applies to you.  What happens if you edit the Xcode project and add the directory to the *Header Search Paths* of the target?

Comment: @trojanfoe Not sure what you mean. The "external" code will be checked in with the rest of my code, so it will apply to whoever grabs my repo and compiles it.

Comment: I assume the Xcode project will be tracked with git, so you can add the directory there, along with any necessary build settings?

Comment: @trojanfoe Also, editing the Xcode project is exactly what I need to avoid because it's the example project, not the plugin itself. So editing the project would mean all consuming projects would need to make the same edits to _their_ project files, duplicating work and making it more fragile to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after *finally* figuring it out.

Something is aggressively caching the "output" of `.podspec` files. What was causing the issue is that I was changing the `.podspec` and cleaning+rebuilding, expecting that to be sufficient to pick up my changes, but it was not. If I instead do a `git clean -xdf` and *then* build, my changes are picked up.

I ended up using the properties I expected should work (with slight tweaks to the above that were easy to figure out once the options were *actually* being used):

```
    s.source_files          = [
        'Classes/**/*',
        'shared_c/**/*'
    ]
    s.public_header_files   = [
        'Classes/**/*.h',
        'shared_c/*.h'
    ]
    s.xcconfig              = {
        'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => [
            '"${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/shared_c/"'
        ],
        'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => 'SOME_SYMBOL_FOR_THIRD_PARTY_CODE=1 SOME_OTHER_SYMBOL=1'
    }
    s.dependency 'Flutter'

    s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
```

As for why the files are being so aggressively cached, I need to chase that up with the Flutter team (and I'm expecting them to say it's a CocoaPods/XCode issue).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every edit to the podspec file also increases its version.

CocoaPods podspecs versions are assumed to be immutable and cached as such. See `pod cache list` and `pod cache clean`.